# WooCommerce Вариативный товар ссылкой на другой сайт

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

столкнулся с проблемой что на сайте издания надо выполнить задачу на WP + Woocommerce
Дано : есть вариативный товар, 1) бумажный вариант, 2) электронный вариант.
Задача : с бумажным вариантом все также, добавить, корзина и т.д., но  при выборе второго/электронного варианта - кнопка должна сразу перекидывать на другой сайт, игнорируя корзину и пр. как обычная статичная кнопка
В админке при добавлении товара прикрутил добавление ссылки для каждого товара отдельно, при обычном echo $link_field; можно посмотреть ссылку, но я уже все облазил и не могу понять как можно прикрутить эту ссылку на второй вариант товара что бы он просто перебрасывал на другой сайт
Если кто знает решение/плагин/статью с такой же задачей - прошу помочь
Согласен даже на прямые костыли, но что бы ссылка могла притягиваться из $link_field;(на каждой странице продукта своя ссылка) в которую эта ссылка будет отправляться

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Приведи вопрос в читабельный вид и убери не нужные теги.